# wedge product of projective planes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

If we have the wedge product of the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2 \vee \mathbb{RP}^2$.

Then how would i use Seifert Van Kampens theorem to compute the fundamental group $\pi_1$($\mathbb{RP}^2 \vee \mathbb{RP}^2$ ) ?

I'm some what confused on Van Kampens theorem especially when applying it to the real projective plane

any help on this would be greatly appreciated! thank you

Comment: how do you define this wedge product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Seifert-van Kampen will give the answer: $\pi_1(P^2\vee P^2)=\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: thank you, as the fundamental group of $P^2$ = $\mathbb{Z}_2$ could you elaborate as to how you got to this stage?

Comment: Seifert-van Kampen says that if $X=A\cup B$, but $A\cap B$ is a point, then $\pi_(X)=\pi_1(A)*\pi_1(B)$ i.e. their free product.

Comment: ah of course, from the definition of the wedge product there exists only a single point of intersection, thanks!

Comment: you are thru man

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0$ be the point of $P^2 \vee P^2$ where we glued the two copies of $P^2$ together.

Recall that to apply Van Kampen theorem (and obtain an isomorphism), we need to write $P^2 \vee P^2$ as the union of path-connected open sets, each containing $x_0$, such that the intersection of any three is path-connected. We should aim to write $P^2 \vee P^2$ using only two path-connected open sets, as that will make our job much easier.

My hint would be to take advantage of the fact that you have two copies of $P^2$, which you know is path-connected (right?) and whose fundamental group you know (right?), after all you should want to write the fundamental group of $P^2 \vee P^2$ (what should your basepoint be?) in terms of some well-known group.

Comment: thanks for the answer! im guessing a good choice of base point would be the point where the two copies join?

Comment: @user123 So long as you take advantage of it!

Comment: @user123 You should also only accept my answer if it has completely satisfied you.

Comment: or wait a little more to see if there are more answers XD

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks again! and sorry its the first day of me using this forum i need to get used to the rules!